# Python read non-ascii text file

Tags: python, utf-8

I am trying to load a text file, which contains some German letters with

```
content=open("file.txt","r").read()
```

which results in this error message

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)
```

if I modify the file to contain only ASCII characters everything works as expected.

Apperently using

```
content=open("file.txt","rb").read()
```

or

```
content=open("file.txt","r",encoding="utf-8").read()
```

both do the job.

Why is it possible to read with "binary" mode and get the same result as with utf-8 encoding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASCII is limited to characters in the range of [0,128).  If you try to decode a byte that is outside that range, one gets that error.

When you read the string in as bytes, you're "widening" the acceptable range of character to [0,256).  So your \0xc3 character `Ã` is now read in without error.  But despite it seeming to work, it's still not "correct".

If your strings are indeed unicode encoded, then the possibility exists that one will contain a multibyte character, that is, a character whose byte representation actually spans multiple bytes.

It is in this case where the difference between reading a file as a byte string and properly decoding it will be quite apparent.

A character like this: č

Will be read in as two bytes, but properly decoded, will be one character:

```
bytes = bytes('č', encoding='utf-8')

print(len(bytes))                   # 2
print(len(bytes.decode('utf-8')))   # 1
```

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3, using 'r' mode and not specifying an encoding just uses a default encoding, which in this case is ASCII. Using 'rb' mode reads the file as bytes and makes no attempt to interpret it as a string of characters.

Comment: Ok, I see `type(open(ULF_DIR+"Banken.txt","rb").read())` returns "bytes" and `type(open(ULF_DIR+"Banken.txt","r",encoding="utf-8").read())`  returns str.  I wrote the output to another file and was confused, because the resulting file looked the same on both methods and I ignored the different types after the input of the data.